casting to float with 4+ zeros after the decimal point
I need to cast the string "0.00003" to a float where the result is 0.00003, and not the scientific notation of 3e-5
float() has a "feature" that any value passed in with 4 or more leading zero's after the decimal returns a value in scientific notation.
Any value passed to float() with less than 4 zero's after the decimal point results in a float.
float("0.0003") results in 0.0003, type(float("0.0003")) returns <class 'float'>
Using float() with 4 or more zero's after the decimal point results in a scientific notation value.
float("0.00003") results in a float of 3e-5
Yes, 3e-5 is value equivalent to 0.00003, but my use case requires that the conversion results in a float data type with the format of 0.00003, and not in scientific notation.
I can't use a formatter like f'{float("0.00003"):.5f}' since this returns a string, and I need a float.
ETA: I'm not printing the value, the value is written to a file in json :
{
    "id": 34677,
    "value": 0.00003
}

The values are originally taken from a csv file:
"34677", "0.00003"
The ID is converted to an int, and the value field needs to be converted to a float where the float has the value 0.00003
There is a validation step where the value key/value pair needs to exactly match the format and value taken from the CSV file - which is why I can't accept 3e-5 as the result of the float("0.00003")
Regardless, my original question is still on point - I need to cast the string "0.00003" to a float where the result is 0.00003, and not the scientific notation of 3e-5

float is a type that has a value and a default display representation.  If you want to display it differently, you have to print it the way you want it.  0.00003 and 3e-5 are just two different ways of displaying the same float value as a string.

updated my post, not printing or displaying the value, but saving it.  Which is why it needs to be a float

JSON is a text string in a file.  It doesn't care if it is 0.00003 or 3e-5.  You'll get the same float back on json.load.  json.loads('0.00003') == json.loads('3e-5') returns True.

while true, this doesn't address my issue - I need to cast the string "0.00003" to a float where the result is 0.00003, and not the scientific notation of 3e-5

Why? A machine will read the JSON correctly either way.  The bytes that are stored for the actual float value in memory are exactly the same.

It sounds like your validation step is invalid.  3e-5 is valid JSON.

nothing to do with bytes stored.  I'm storing literals and doing a post-process compare.  Because, it is my use case is why.  I've updated the original Q again with more info.  I do appreciate the help but none of this is an answer to my question.  Converting the string "0.00003" into a float that is 0.00003 where a type() of the return is "float" is the problem I'm trying to solve


"It sounds like your validation step is invalid."  Lol, I'll be sure to let my PM know


That is not possible.  float, when printed, is converted to a string with default rules.  You have to format it as a string if it isn't what you want.

You can derive a different class from float and override its __repr__ or __str__ methods for a custom display.

You can use Decimal for that:
from decimal import Decimal

input_str = "0.00003"

decimal_value = Decimal(input_str)

# When you need to display the value, you can use the decimal object for precise control
print(f'{decimal_value:.5f}')  # This will display 0.00003


f'{decimal_value:.5f}') results in a string, not a float
type(f'{decimal_value:.5f}')
<class 'str'>

That is correct because you are printing it. A value is converted to a str when printing. For other usage you can use Decimal.

I'm not printing it, I'm storing it into a json array

Have you tried to use Decimal object how it was mentioned in the answer?

Solution:
import json

class FormattedFloat(float):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None
json.encoder.float = FormattedFloat

x = FormattedFloat("0.00003")

x = my desired float value as 0.00003 where the type() is FormattedFloat
